# Get all functions inside a Python Package for getattr

Tags: python, django, getattr

I have two python files and both at same directory level like this

```
project
      |> tasks.py
      |> queue.py
```

I have a function like this in `tasks.py` file

```
def foo(message):
    # perform some functions on message data
    # blah blah
```

and another function in `queue.py` file like this

```
import project.tasks
def run_task(function_name, data):
    # function name is a string which tells which function to call in tasks.py file
    return getattr(project.tasks, function_name)(data)
```

I do not want to hard code my function name. I want to access them dynamically on the basis of `function_name` parameter. My `tasks.py` has become very large therefore I want to divide it in parts. The thing which I did is I moved `tasks.py` file in a python package like this.

```
project
      |> tasks
              |> __init__.py
              |> tasks.py
      |> queue.py
```

The question which I want to ask is that how I can modify my `run_task` function in order to work for this struction. As `getattr` function task first argument an object. Is there any other option avilable which I can used to access function inside `task` package.?

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify `run_tasks`, just `from .tasks import *` in the `__init__.py` to expose all names in `tasks.py` from the `tasks`module.

Comment: If I do `from .tasks import *` I get error `import * only allowed at module level`. In my case, i want to change tasks module to tasks package.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `tasks` package can have multiple files.

Comment: Error from what? Is that a linter of some kind? Which, and which version of Python are you using? Could you give a [mcve] will the full output?

Comment: Yes, of course it can have multiple files, so you have an `import `line *for each file* in the `__init__.py`.

Comment: Oh.... I got it. I was not correctly following your answer. Let me try it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanx it works. Kindly post your comment as answer and I will accept it. Thanx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @jonrsharpe comment.
Put following in  in the `__init__.py`

> from .tasks import *

to expose all names in `tasks.py` from the tasks module. Do it for all files you have in `tasks` package.